# what means "return+" in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Found some code which implements the Date.now function for older browsers, code is

```
Date.now=Date.now||function(){return+(new Date)};
```

what does the `+` operator do ? cant find anything on the net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the doc:

> **Unary plus (+)**
>
> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its
>   operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't
>   already. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers,
>   unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something
>   into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the
>   number. It can convert string representations of integers and floats,
>   as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in
>   both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported.
>   Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot
>   parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

**Syntax**

> Operator: +x

**Examples**

```
+3     // 3
+"3"   // 3
+true  // 1
+false // 0
+null  // 0
```

**References**

[Arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Comment: thanks a lot for the well explained answer

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the Date object into an integer. It represents the number of miliseconds since 1/1/1970